# Highcharts Y Axis Tick Marks not setting

Tags: highcharts

So I am trying to dynamically reset the tick markers for a chart. Let's say that you have a text input that allows the user to enter a number and then the code resets the tick marks to that number. The length is resetting, but the width appears not to be.

I am using the command

```
chart.yAxis[0].options.tickWidth=parseInt($('#tickwidth').val());
chart.yAxis[0].options.tickLength=parseInt($('#tickwidth').val());
```

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jfoxworth/j4rQT/) Just enter a number in the text box and then click off the text box somewhere. The code sets the length and height of the tick marks to that number. Only the width isn't working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unforunately this option is not available, only what you can do is destroy and create new chart.

Comment: Appreciate the answer. Is this possible on the X axis?

Comment: It is the same sitatuon as in the yAxis. Axis are genereted in the same way.